# Error when creating dataframe "*** ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was trying to create a plot with seaborn, but I faced an error:

```
*** ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

In my program I have read an output file from XFOIL and was trying to plot its results to check it out.

XFOIL File format:

```
#      x          Cp  
     1.00000    0.24276
     0.99818    0.23883
     0.99591    0.22657
     0.99342    0.21421
     0.99066    0.20128
     0.98759    0.18802
     0.98413    0.17434
     0.98020    0.16018
     0.97569    0.14544
     0.97044    0.12999
     0.96429    0.11374
     0.95703    0.09661
### **(the file is big, and I will not transcript it completely here)** ###
```

I decided to create a dataframe to enable the plotting process easily.

```
lst = fl.readlines()
lst_splt = [ s.replace('#','').split() for s in lst] 
cp = pd.DataFrame.from_records(lst_splt[1:], columns=lst_splt[:1]).astype(float)
```

and finally I tried to plot it using seaborn:

```
sns.lineplot(x='x',y='Cp', data=cp)
```

but as I said on the beginning of the question, an error appeared:

```
*** ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

What can I do to fix this error?

Comment: Could you try to add the index=[0] into the argument **DataFrame.from_records(data, index=[0])** ? I can't replicate the scenario you have but that has worked for me previously.

Comment: Did you try to check that the DataFrame looks like what you expect it to? Does it? Did you try to check (for example, by reading the documentation) that Seaborn wants the data arranged that way? What happened when you tried copying and pasting `If using all scalar values, you must pass an index` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=If+using+all+scalar+values%2C+you+must+pass+an+index)?

Comment: Are you sure the error appears on `sns.lineplot` and not on the unusual looking `pd.DataFrame.from_records`. Can you print out `cp.head()` just after the dataframe creation?

Comment: with `cp = pd.read_csv(flname,'r', sep='\s+',skiprows=(3), header=None, index=[0])` the error `*** TypeError: read_csv() got multiple values for argument 'sep'` persists on read cp. I didn"t managed to get to `sns.lineplot` with this modification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Not sure why you are having this error, but</s> you can simply do:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(cp["x"], cp["Cp"])
plt.show()
```

EDIT: After some experimentation, it seems that your method for creating the dataframe is probably the culprit. You can replace it with:

```py
cp = pd.read_csv(filename, sep="\s+", skiprows=2, names=["x", "Cp"])
# Make sure that you have the right value for skiprows (should ignore the header and that's it)

# Then this works:
sns.lineplot(x="x", y="Cp", data=cp)
```

Comment: Seems to me that this does not answer OP specific question which is to deal with his XFOIL file format.

Comment: Using the first method you presented works properly. I had already tried that before. But I am still curious about the error. I tried something similar to that wit seaborn and the error persisted.

Comment: Yes, have you tried to replace the file opening > read into dataframe with the function `pd.read_csv` as mentioned in my post? This should work for your file format and give you the result you want

Comment: About the second process, I tried and It worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: If I use directely in the read_csv as `cp = pd.read_csv(flname,'r', sep='\s+',skiprows=(3), header=None)`, I get the following error: `*** TypeError: read_csv() got multiple values for argument 'sep'`. When I tried to read first and put in a `stringIO`, then I get the desired result

Comment: Remove "r" (second argument), it has no place there...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related to the `columns` argument passed to the `DataFrame` constructor.

When printing `lst_splt[:1]`, which is the value you pass to the `columns` argument, I get this:

```
print(lst_splt[:1])
# [['x', 'Cp']]
```

The `Dataframe` constructor in this case needs a flat list, not a nested one. The problem is solved when you change `lst_splt[:1]` to `lst_splt[:1][0]` which when printed gives of course:

```
print(lst_splt[:1][0])
# ['x', 'Cp']
```

The modified verrsion of your code below works fine:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

fl = open('data.txt', 'r')

lst = fl.readlines()
lst_splt = [ s.replace('#','').split() for s in lst]
cp = pd.DataFrame.from_records(lst_splt[1:], columns=lst_splt[:1][0]).astype(float)

sns.lineplot(data=cp, x='x',y='Cp')

plt.show()
```

out:
[image]

Comment: I liked the approach you proposed! Thanks a lot! It will help me in some other problems too!